# Libgdx: touchDragged, the object is not moved touch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My code moves an object by clicking on it and on the touch, I want to just touch on the moving object. How to disable the ability to navigate the click event object

```
  Vector3 touchPos;
   touchPos = new Vector3();
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);


  @Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

    touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(touchPos);
    bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your `touchDragged` method missing a parameter?

```
public void touchDragged( InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer )
```

The `event` object has 2 methods for affecting the propagation of an event,`setBubbles(boolean)` and `cancel()`.

Also, the methods `touchDown` and `touchUp` should have the same `event` parameter.